# How do I get crisp large denomination bills in a another country's currency?

Tags: canada

I'm flying flying from the US to Canada for a wedding soon and for various reasons (no registry, nonexistent baggage allowance, the couple lives in a small apartment) would like to give cash as a wedding present.

My experience with ATMs is that they frequently provide only $20 bills that are not in a condition I'd like to put in a fancy box with a nice note.

Do you have any recommendations? My current plan is just to seek out a brick and mortar bank once I'm in Canada and ask, but I'm not sure that they'll be willing to accommodate someone who doesn't bank with them.

Comment: Why can't you get large Canadian bills from your own US bank? Is there a customs cash limit? If they aren't very flat, you can flatten them overnight by placing under a hardback book with a heavy weight on top, like a stack of more books, or an actual weight if you have one.

Comment: This might sound really weird but depending on the consistency of the note you can use hair straighteners to make them look super crisp and new if you can't get access to new notes. (based on my experiences with UK notes it works perfectly and makes them look brand new)

Comment: @WeatherVane I did not realize they would provide that service (some cash maybe but not specific bills) and thought the exchange rate would be terrible

Comment: I believe you can order currency in advance - the banks only stock the most common ones. You can look up the exchange rates? Note that if you buy them in Canada on your credit card, it could be expensive as you are drawing cash.

Comment: Just as a heads-up in case you haven't been to Canada in a while, and are basing your ATM experience on American ATMs:  Canada has had [polymer (plastic) banknotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontier_(banknotes)) for several years now, which generally don't show "wear" as much as paper banknotes.  You might be surprised by how "crisp" the average $20 or $50 bill from the ATM is;  it may be a non-issue.

Comment: Would a pre-paid Visa card be an option, instead of cash?

Comment: @Uciebila Does your technique work with polymer banknotes?

Comment: Thanks all! Will try my bank and then visa card or ATM (one of the bridesmaids likely will have a hair straightener) if bank doesn't work

Comment: @MikeHarris my technique works with polymer notes. When the corner of a paper note gets a dog-ear it is easy to unfold it, but one on a polymer note will not stay unfolded, unless you slide it between the pages of a book so as to open the fold, and weight the book overnight with a couple of bricks. When polymer money is folded in general, it is much harder to flatten than paper.